# Separate a column in dataframe where each observation can have multiple concurrent values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I believe my question is as much about best practice as it is about tidying messy data, so here goes.

Below is an excerpt of the dataframe `lang.df`, a school-wide dataset of students. The column, `Langauge.Home`, indicates parent responses to the question:
"What languages do you speak at home?"

```
> lang.df
   Nationality             Language.Home
1           HK                  Mandarin
2       German   Mandarin/English/German
3        Saudi                    Arabic
4    Norwegian                 Norwegian
5           UK                   English
6           HK Mandarin/ Min Nan dialect
7   Australian                  Mandarin
8           HK                  Mandarin
9    Brazilian        Portuguese/English
10      Indian             Hindi/English
```

It is obvious to me that this is a poor way to get this information as well as a poor way to store it, but my job is to use the data I have.

**Outcome**

I want to explore the effect that certain home languages might have on achievement. What I need is the ability to subset the by a single langauge spoken at home (e.g. the students who speak English at home).

To do so, it seems I have to separate the `Language@home` column into three (`"language.home1", "language.home2", "language.home3"`) using dplyr's `separate()`. The create a new column for each unique value (i.e. language) in the new columns I created

**Process**

Below is my attempt at doing the above, efficiently

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#separate Langauge.Home into three new columns
lang.df <- lang.df %>% separate(Language.Home,
        c("language.home1", "language.home2", "language.home3"),
        sep = "/",
        remove = FALSE)

#find distinct languages & remove NAs
langs <- unique(c(lang.df$language.home1,
    lang.df$language.home2,
    lang.df$language.home3))
langs <- langs[!is.na(langs)]

#create boolean column for each unique language in new columns
for (i in langs) {
lang.df[,paste(i)] <- grepl(i, lang.df$Language.Home) 
}
```

**Questions**

1. What is this situation called? I tried to look at the `tidyr` docs and here on SO but couldn't find anything about it.
2. Is there a more elegant way to code the transformations than what I have done?
3. What is best practice for

   - Getting this data (to change future data entry process)
   - Dealing with this situation from a statistical perspective

Thanks in advance for your help. I've only been using R on-and-off for  about a year now and this is my first SO post. Give me as much feedback as you can!

**Data**

```
lang.df <- structure(list(Nationality = structure(c(4L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("Australian", "Brazilian", "German", 
"HK", "Indian", "Norwegian", "Saudi", "UK"), class = "factor"), 
`Language.Home` = structure(c(4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 8L, 3L), .Label = c("Arabic", "English", "Hindi/English", 
"Mandarin", "Mandarin/ Min Nan dialect", "Mandarin/English/German", 
"Norwegian", "Portuguese/English"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), .Names = c("Nationality", "Language.Home"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try also: `cSplit_e(lang.df, "Language.Home", "/", type = "character", fill = 0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` to split the 'Language.Home' using the delimiter `/` and to convert it to `long` format.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)
dt <- cSplit(lang.df, "Language.Home", "/", "long")
```

Then, use `dcast` to convert from 'long' to 'wide'

```
dcast(dt, Nationality~Language.Home, fun.aggregate = function(x) length(x)>0)
```

NOTE: There are duplicate 'Nationality' rows, so the above will group the common elements together.  It may be better to group it together.

If we need to have logical columns based on each row (irrespective of similar 'Nationality')

```
 dcast(cSplit(setDT(lang.df, keep.rownames=TRUE), "Language.Home",
   "/", "long"), rn +Nationality ~Language.Home, function(x) length(x) >0)
```

---

Or another option is `mtabulate` from `qdapTools` after splitting the 'Language.Home' by `/`.

```
 library(qdapTools)
 cbind(lang.df, !!(mtabulate(setNames(strsplit(as.character(lang.df$Language.Home), 
                 "/"), lang.df$Nationality))))
#   Nationality             Language.Home  Min Nan dialect Arabic English German Hindi Mandarin Norwegian Portuguese
#1           HK                  Mandarin            FALSE  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE     TRUE     FALSE      FALSE
#2       German   Mandarin/English/German            FALSE  FALSE    TRUE   TRUE FALSE     TRUE     FALSE      FALSE
#3        Saudi                    Arabic            FALSE   TRUE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE    FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
#4    Norwegian                 Norwegian            FALSE  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE    FALSE      TRUE      FALSE
#5           UK                   English            FALSE  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE FALSE    FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
#6           HK Mandarin/ Min Nan dialect             TRUE  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE     TRUE     FALSE      FALSE
#7   Australian                  Mandarin            FALSE  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE     TRUE     FALSE      FALSE
#8           HK                  Mandarin            FALSE  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE     TRUE     FALSE      FALSE
#9    Brazilian        Portuguese/English            FALSE  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE FALSE    FALSE     FALSE       TRUE
#10      Indian             Hindi/English            FALSE  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE  TRUE    FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted; thanks, @akrun !
Can you tell me when it would be better to have it in the long format?

Also for my own future reference: [this r bloggers post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-splitstackshape-package-for-r/) was what I spent forever trying to find

Comment: @AndersSwanson  Thank you for the feedback.  Converting to long format depends on the type of analysis you want to perform.  If you are doing some graphics with ggplot, perhaps long format is the one you wanted to do.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to get to long form is with `tidyr::unnest()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

lang.df %>% 
  mutate(Language.Home = str_split(Language.Home, "/")) %>% 
  unnest()
#>    Nationality    Language.Home
#> 1           HK         Mandarin
#> 2       German         Mandarin
#> 3       German          English
#> 4       German           German
#> 5        Saudi           Arabic
#> 6    Norwegian        Norwegian
#> 7           UK          English
#> 8           HK         Mandarin
#> 9           HK  Min Nan dialect
#> 10  Australian         Mandarin
#> 11          HK         Mandarin
#> 12   Brazilian       Portuguese
#> 13   Brazilian          English
#> 14      Indian            Hindi
#> 15      Indian          English
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base approach which is only a few lines in total

```
lang.df <- structure(list(Nationality = structure(c(4L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("Australian", "Brazilian", "German", "HK", "Indian", "Norwegian", "Saudi", "UK"), class = "factor"), `Language.Home` = structure(c(4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 3L), .Label = c("Arabic", "English", "Hindi/English", "Mandarin", "Mandarin/ Min Nan dialect", "Mandarin/English/German", "Norwegian", "Portuguese/English"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), .Names = c("Nationality", "Language.Home"), class = "data.frame")
```

Second part: new data frame with each language split into separate columns and labeled sequentially

```
dd <- read.table(text = gsub('/\\s*', ';', lang.df$Language.Home),
                 sep = ';', na.strings = '', fill = TRUE, as.is = TRUE,
                 col.names = paste0('lang.home', 1:3))
#      lang.home1      lang.home2 lang.home3
#   1    Mandarin            <NA>       <NA>
#   2    Mandarin         English     German
#   3      Arabic            <NA>       <NA>
#   4   Norwegian            <NA>       <NA>
#   5     English            <NA>       <NA>
#   6    Mandarin Min Nan dialect       <NA>
#   7    Mandarin            <NA>       <NA>
#   8    Mandarin            <NA>       <NA>
#   9  Portuguese         English       <NA>
#  10       Hindi         English       <NA>
```

Third part: logical indicator for each unique language

```
lang <- na.omit(sort(unique(unlist(dd))))
idx <- `colnames<-`(t(apply(dd, 1, function(x) lang %in% x)), lang)

#       Arabic English German Hindi Mandarin Min Nan dialect Norwegian Portuguese
#  [1,]  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE     TRUE           FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
#  [2,]  FALSE    TRUE   TRUE FALSE     TRUE           FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
#  [3,]   TRUE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE    FALSE           FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
#  [4,]  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE    FALSE           FALSE      TRUE      FALSE
#  [5,]  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE FALSE    FALSE           FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
#  [6,]  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE     TRUE            TRUE     FALSE      FALSE
#  [7,]  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE     TRUE           FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
#  [8,]  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE     TRUE           FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
#  [9,]  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE FALSE    FALSE           FALSE     FALSE       TRUE
# [10,]  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE  TRUE    FALSE           FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
```

Combine three parts:

```
cbind(lang.df, dd, idx)

#    Nationality             Language.Home lang.home1      lang.home2 lang.home3 Arabic English German Hindi Mandarin Min Nan dialect Norwegian Portuguese
# 1           HK                  Mandarin   Mandarin            <NA>       <NA>  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE     TRUE           FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
# 2       German   Mandarin/English/German   Mandarin         English     German  FALSE    TRUE   TRUE FALSE     TRUE           FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
# 3        Saudi                    Arabic     Arabic            <NA>       <NA>   TRUE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE    FALSE           FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
# 4    Norwegian                 Norwegian  Norwegian            <NA>       <NA>  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE    FALSE           FALSE      TRUE      FALSE
# 5           UK                   English    English            <NA>       <NA>  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE FALSE    FALSE           FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
# 6           HK Mandarin/ Min Nan dialect   Mandarin Min Nan dialect       <NA>  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE     TRUE            TRUE     FALSE      FALSE
# 7   Australian                  Mandarin   Mandarin            <NA>       <NA>  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE     TRUE           FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
# 8           HK                  Mandarin   Mandarin            <NA>       <NA>  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE FALSE     TRUE           FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
# 9    Brazilian        Portuguese/English Portuguese         English       <NA>  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE FALSE    FALSE           FALSE     FALSE       TRUE
# 10      Indian             Hindi/English      Hindi         English       <NA>  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE  TRUE    FALSE           FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
```